# How to iterate through a table in Javascript and swap specified cells with each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with an id of "mytable", and I have a for loop that builds a 4x4 table, giving each cell an id from 0 to 15 and setting the innerHTML equal to that same number. Once cell is left blank, as this is going to be part of a sliding puzzle game where a user presses a button which scrambles the cells of the table, the solves it by shifting cell positions into that blank space. My issue at the moment is that I can't seem to implement a shuffle function that works. Below is my my code for building a table and shuffling it. See the comments for the error message.

```
function buildTable(){//need to build it with every cell being named
    var tablelocation = document.getElementById('mytable'); 
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.id="newtable";
    for(var i = 0; i<tableSize; i++){
        var tableRow = table.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j<tableSize; j++){
            var arrTmp = (tableSize*tableSize-1)-(i*tableSize+j);
            var cell = tableRow.insertCell();
            cell.id = arrTmp;       
            if(arrTmp==15){
                cell.className = "empty_cell";
            else{
                cell.className = "cell";    
                cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arrTmp));
            }

        }
    }

    tablelocation.appendChild(table);
}
```

Because the table is built from the bottom right to the top left I have a variable, that handles the values so that once the table is built the numbers appear in the table from 0 to 15 from top left to bottom right.

```
function shuffleTable(){//need to build it with every cell being named


    var table = document.getElementById("newtable");
    for (var i = 0; i<tableArray.length; i++) {
        var tmp = tableArray[i];//array of shuffled ID values
        var tmp2 = objectCellArray[tmp];
        objectCellArrayShuffled.push(tmp2);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j<tableArray.length; j++){
        var cell = table.cells[j];//fails here with undefined is not an object error
        cell = objectCellArrayShuffled[j];
    }
}
```

I'm calling shuffleTable with a button on my html page.

Comment: Why don't you loop from top left to bottom right and increment `i` accordingly? Print `table.cells` using `console.debug()` to see what's happening.

Comment: I did that and it gave me 16 instances of "undefined" - sorry, I'm just sort of new to js and I'm not really familiar with debugging techniques.

Comment: What doesn't work about your shuffle function? Fully explaining the problem can help us help you.

Comment: If you look in the shuffleTable function you'll see a comment that says "fails here with undefined is not an object error." That is where the code is failing, according to my debugger.

Comment: Make sure before your 'else' keyword, you have a closing curly brace (`}`). And `tableSize` is undefined. Can we see the code that initializes this? Really, everything you have in a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) would be excellent.

Comment: @JLH Exacty, the `table` object has no `cells` attribute. In my opinion, HTML tables are made to build static grids, not a fluid matrix of cells. I would build a classic 4x4 table and just move their content (an `<img>` tag) or swap their backgrounds (if you know CSS).

Comment: Just a word of warning. A `<table>` does not lend itself very well to visualizing a sliding puzzle, since "sliding" `<td>`s between rows is more hassle than necessary. Try working a 4x4 grid of positioned `<div>` elements.

Comment: Okay, I see that part of my problem is that the table I'm using is just...not really good for that purpose. The project was an assignment and the professor has refused to give input or advice on the matter. It's not an ideal situation, but that's what stackoverflow is for I suppose. I managed to get the solution working on my end, but I'm going to re-code it to replace the table with positioned div elements.